# PHP: How to escape the url params and path without encoding the Scheme and Host in URL?

Tags: php, url-encoding

PHP: How to escape the URL params and path without encoding the Scheme and Host in URL:

**Please notice* this url is just an example params might be named different than q and some urls might have path others might not, like the example below.**

I get the url as follows:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F?q=My%20Search%20Keyword
```

Then I should converted to the following:

```
http://google.com/?q=My%20Search%20Keyword
```

not:

```
http://google.com/?q=My Search Keyword
```

is there an easy way for doing this, other than

1. Url decoding the whole url, via "rawurldecode"
2. "parse_url" to split it to scheme, domain, path, query
3. Parse the query with parse_str and escape the values only.
4. Rebuild the query string
5. Rebuild the url back,
6. All the steps above require checking for empty values too.

**UPDATE**

In more complicated case I get the URL like this:

```
http://www.someUrl.com/?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F%3Fq%3DMy%20Search%20Keyword%26hl%3Den
```

Where I search for =http..... then I use this part to crawl it via Curl and get the http response code from this url, the problem is that I can't easily prepare the url which was sent ecnoded from the beginning without involving the complicated process I mentioned above.

**is there an easier way of doing this ?**

Comment: you could explode on `?q=` if thats the only variable in the strong

Comment: This is just an example, I'm processing millions of different urls, none of them are Google urls

Comment: well i can only make segestions based on what you post

Comment: o.k. I added a note, that this is just an example url

Comment: strange idea, give an actual example

Comment: This is an Identical example,This is just a different domain

Comment: I think you don't need to unescape url's path since it can't contain encoded characters. You have to unescape url's query only.

Comment: @hidmost, how can I escape the values only without escaping & =

Comment: Replace the first occurrence of `%3A` with `:` and then replace the next three occurrences of `%2F` with `/`? That will make the url look like `http://google.com/?q=My%20Search%20Keyword`

Comment: @Shehabix Sorry, I did mean you need to unescape all except the query

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just explode on the `?`, then `rawurldecode` the first part, then implode?

```
$url = "http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F?q=My%20Search%20Keyword";
$parts = explode("?", $url);
$parts[0] = rawurldecode($parts[0]);
$url = implode("?", $parts);
```

Comment: Yes, I think this would work even if the Url is paramless..
Let me try first then I'll mark it correct or incorrect ..

Comment: I voted up for your Answer as it's not exactly the correct one, but it's an approach

Comment: where there are 2 params and both are escaped with the & sign escaped as well, may be it was a problem in my question not to mention all cases

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$rawUrl = 'http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F?q=My%20Search%20Keyword';
$arrDec = parse_url(urldecode($rawUrl)); 
$queryEnc = parse_url($rawUrl, PHP_URL_QUERY);

$newUrl = $arrDec['scheme'] . '://' . $arrDec['host'] . '?' . $queryEnc;

print_r($newUrl);

?>
```

Here's a phpFiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/wmi-xet

Comment: how about when there are more than 1 params from the beginning?
I'll update my question

Comment: Try my phpFiddle example. It works fine no matter how many params there are.

Comment: for more than 1 param, it doesn't work, please check the update I posted above

Comment: Your update is not clear. What you want to achieve with this last url?

Comment: crawl it with curl, to get the http response

Comment: But do you want to use whole provided URL, or take the url from parameter `redirect`?

Comment: the url from redirect=

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution, it might have flaws, but might help someone else as well ..

```
$url = rawurldecode('http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F%3Fq%3DMy%20Search%20Keyword%26hl%3Den');
echo preg_replace_callback('#[^/\.\:&=\?]{1}#',
    function($str) { return rawurlencode($str[0]);}, 
    $url
);
```